# Configure sub-flow as a bean for PublishSubscribeChannel in Spring integration DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

According to the section [Sub Flows support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#sub-flows-support) of the guide, one would expect to be able to configure a sub-flow very simply: using DSL factories or lambdas.

```java
// This is modified example from the guide.

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subscribersFlow() {
    return flow -> flow
            .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), s -> s
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p / 2)
                            .channel(c -> c.queue("subscriber1Results")))
                    .subscribe(
                            // this.subflow1()
                            this.subflow2()

                    ))
            .<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 3)
            .channel(c -> c.queue("subscriber3Results"));
}

// Attempt 1:
// Just a copy paste of the logic from above.
// Does not work, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subflow1() {
    return f -> f
            .<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 2)
            .channel(c -> c.queue("subscriber2Results"));
}

// Attempt 2:
// Using DSL factories.
// Does not work, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subflow2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.direct())
            .<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 2)
            .channel(c -> c.queue("subscriber2Results"))
            .get();
}
```

I'm getting this exception with the second attempt defined above.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow.configure(StandardIntegrationFlow.java:100)
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.PublishSubscribeSpec.subscribe(PublishSubscribeSpec.java:51)
```

I've tried it with `spring-boot-starter-integration:2.0.0.M3`. Am I missing something ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-flows must not be as beans. You definitely can extract them to their own methods, even `private`. But the wiring everything together you should leave to the Framework.

If you still need them as bean, so use the connection between flows via message channels.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think it was that simple. Just for the record, then, the first attempt works, just need to remove @Bean on the sub-flow definition.